# is there a reason to not put my admin directory in robots.txt?

Tags: php, apache, security

This may have been asked and answered, since I'm not sure what is the best way to phrase this.

I want to ensure that search spiders don't index the admin side of my website.  Unfortunately, if I put the path into my robots.txt file, I'm handing over the cookie jar.  Thankfully it's locked, though.

I've already had quite a few "visitors" who start by grabbing robots.txt.  Obviously, non-legit spiders will ignore robots.txt, but I want to prevent Google and Bing from plastering my admin directory in search results.

- My admin directory is not called "admin" (the most common SBO tactic)
- Directory browsing is already blocked
- Any IP who connects to my admin directory without logging in first with appropriate permissions is blacklisted.  I have been monitoring, and have only had a couple of legit spiders get blacklisted by this manner
- I'm using .htaccess (merging several public blacklists) and PHP blacklisting based on behaviors (some automatic, but still Mark-I eyeball as well)
- All actions on the admin side are auth-based
- The only links to the admin side are presented to authorized users with the appropriate permissions.

I'm not sure if I should put the admin directory in robots.txt - On one hand, legit spiders will ignore that directory, but on the other, I'm telling those who want to do harm that directory exists, and I don't want prying eyes...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to ensure that search spiders don't index the admin side of my website. Unfortunately, if I put the path into my robots.txt file, I'm handing over the cookie jar. Thankfully it's locked, though.

You rightly recognize the conundrum. If you put the admin url in the robots.txt, then well-behaved bots will stay away. On the other hand, you are basically telegraphing to bad folks where the soft spots are.

If you inspect your web server's access log, you will most likely see a LOT of requests for admin-type pages. For instance, looking at the apache log on one of my servers, I see opportunistic script kiddies searching for wordpress, phpmyadmin, etc:

`109.98.109.101 - - [24/Jan/2019:08:48:36 -0600] "GET /wpc.php HTTP/1.1" 404 229 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0)" 109.98.109.101 - - [24/Jan/2019:08:48:36 -0600] "GET /wpo.php HTTP/1.1" 404 229 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0)" 109.98.109.101 - - [24/Jan/2019:08:48:37 -0600] "GET /wp-config.php HTTP/1.1" 404 229 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0)" 109.98.109.101 - - [24/Jan/2019:08:48:43 -0600] "POST /wp-admins.php HTTP/1.1" 404 229 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)" 109.98.109.101 - - [24/Jan/2019:08:50:01 -0600] "GET /wp-content/plugins/portable-phpmyadmin/wp-pma-mod/index.php HTTP/1.1" 404 229 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.108 Safari/537.36 109.98.109.101 - - [24/Jan/2019:08:48:39 -0600] "GET /phpmyadmin/scripts/setup.php HTTP/1.1" 404 229 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0)" 109.98.109.101 - - [24/Jan/2019:08:48:39 -0600] "GET /phpmyadmin/scripts/db___.init.php HTTP/1.1" 404 229 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0)" 109.98.109.101 - - [24/Jan/2019:08:49:35 -0600] "GET /phpmyadmin/index.php HTTP/1.1" 404 229 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.108 Safari/537.36" 109.98.109.101 - - [24/Jan/2019:08:49:47 -0600] "GET /admin/phpmyadmin/index.php HTTP/1.1" 404 229 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.108 Safari/537.36" 109.98.109.101 - - [24/Jan/2019:08:49:47 -0600] "GET /admin/phpmyadmin2/index.php HTTP/1.1" 404 229 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.108 Safari/537.36"`

My access log has thousands upon thousands of these. Bots search for them all the time and *none* of these files are listed in my robots.txt file. As you might guess, unless you have an admin url that is really randomly named, the bad guys could very well guess its name is /admin.

> I've already had quite a few "visitors" who start by grabbing robots.txt. Obviously, non-legit spiders will ignore robots.txt, but I want to prevent Google and Bing from plastering my admin directory in search results.

I'd strongly recommend spending some time banning bad bots or basically any bots that you have no use for. AHrefsBot & SemRushBot come to mind. It shouldn't be too hard to find [bad bot lists](https://github.com/mitchellkrogza/apache-ultimate-bad-bot-blocker/blob/master/robots.txt/robots.txt) but you'll need to evaluate any list you find to make sure it isn't blocking bots you want to serve. In addition to adding an exclusion rule to your robots.txt file, you should probably configure your application to ban bad bots by sending a 403 forbidden or 404 gone or [other HTTP response code of your choice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status).

In the end, it's critical to remember the maxim that "[security by obscurity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity) is not security". One of the most important principles of encryption and security is [Kerckhoff's Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerckhoffs%27s_principle) -- i.e., "the enemy knows the system." Your site should not just rely on the location of your admin urls being obscure or secret. You must **require authentication** and use sound best practices in your authentication code. I would not rely on apache authentication but would instead code my web application to accept user login/password in a securely-hosted form (use HTTPS) and I would store only the hashed form of those passwords. **Do not store cleartext passwords ever.**

In the end, the security of your system is only as good as the weakest link. There is some value to having a unique or unusual admin because you might be exposed to fewer attacks, but this in itself doesn't provide any real security. If you still have reservations about broadcasting this url in your robots.txt file, perhaps weigh that against the problems you might expect if GoogleBot or BingBot or some other friendly bot starts stomping around in your admin urls. Would it bother you if these urls ended up in the google search index?

Comment: As shown in the question, Security by Obscurity is only one of the six methods being used to protect the admin directory, any functionality or information contained within.

Comment: @Chameleon The steps you've taken seem prudent, but it's impossible to judge if you might have vulnerabilities without seeing code, etc.

Comment: I was hoping to see additional thoughts.  I believe that while securing assets, one should use as many tools as are available.  While it is true that SBO is as effective as scotch tape holding a door closed, hiding a door you don't want people to open is one more speed bump along the way to breaching that door.

NOT putting it in robots.txt places me in the position where it is more likely that Google and Bing will publicize the admin directory, which is far more publicity than my putting it in robots.txt

Comment: Note that "404" is a "Not Found". The "410" code is "Gone"... But 404 is probably best to not leak any information.

Answer (score 0):

You ask about `robots.txt` and how to prevent your `/admin` path from being indexed. First of all, search engines like Google can tell the type of page for the most part and will rarely index such. When was the last time you clicked on a link on Google and ended up on an admin, login, contact, or such page? They strive for content.

On the other hand, the `robots.txt` is not a good idea if you don't want bad robots (hackers) from finding your hidden pages. One way is to mark your "secret" pages with `NOINDEX` like so:

```
<meta name="robots" content="noindex">
```

You can also send a header, but all search engines don't recognize those:

```
X-Robots-Tag: noindex
```

Or even better, put both.

More details on how to [Block Search indexes with noindex](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/crawling-indexing/block-indexing).